# How do I get redux-form to update state from dynamically set form fields?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm building a [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/) in my React web app where the user can enter their postcode, and an address lookup service provides a list of possible addresses.

After selecting an address, the address form fields are populated by the service provider's script - however, my problem is that I'm unsure how to get redux-form to see that the fields have been updated.

The present outcome is that the state is unaware of the new textinput values that have been dynamically set.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To give an answer, one would need to see what your code is presently doing

Answer (score 0):

Your options are either:

1. In your form component, put an `onChange` listener ([released in `v6.5.0`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v6.5.0)) on your `postCode` field that handles the async and then calls `this.props.change('street', retrievedStreet)` for each of your other fields to populate them.
2. Have some Redux middleware that listens to `CHANGE` actions on `postCode` and does the same.

The former seems easier, assuming you're not doing any complex `redux-saga` or `redux-observable` craziness in your Redux layer.